# Need help setting upo Fedora (or CentOS) networking where VMs are bridged to external network cards

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, vnc

I have a RedHat style linux machine (currently running Fedora 21) which is host for a variety of virtual machines with variety of guest operating systems. It is essential for my purpose that the virtual machines can use libpcap and libnet to access non-IP protocols on the external physical network.
I once had everything running just right, but it broke when the host OS was upgraded from Fedora 19 to Fedora 21.
Currently, I have the host OS running, and everything seems right EXCEPT that I cannot get the VNC server to communicate with the outside world. SSHD runs fine, but VNC connections time out. Fro m the physical console screen, I can connect to the VNC server using 127.0.0.1, so I know the server is running. There is no firewall filtering.

Any suggestions on how to debug this problem?

Comment: What VM system are you using. Have you checked the settings for network access between VMs?

Comment: My immediate problem is that the VNC server will not allow incoming connections, and I cannot figure out how that could be. I have created a second virtual bridge "br0""

Comment: I am using qemu-kvm.
In the host machine I have created a virtual bridge "br0" in addition to the automatically created "virbr0". I have included the external ethernet card in the "br0" and configured "br0" as the active ethernet interface for the host system.
I have verified that the VNC server is running, and I can access it from a local viewer. The iptables firewall has been disabled.
I figure there is no point in trying to get into the virtual machines until I can first get into the host system.